# After importing pictures into Aperture how can I find them in Finder?

Tags: finder, aperture

When I import pictures from my camera using Aperture I can find them by using Aperture to browse through its library, but I generally want to access them from Finder.

Where might they be?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your use of Aperture if you "generally want to access them from the Finder". The point of Apps like Aperture, iPhoto et al is that they replace the finder for anything you want to do with your photos, and as they use enormous amounts of virtualisation most of the data you add in Aperture - edits etc, metadata and so on - simply aren't available in the Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click on the package used as Aperture Library, and select "Show Package Contents," Finder will show you the directories contained in the package; inside "Masters" you will find the pictures.
In my case, they are contained in a subdirectory of "Masters."

Comment: Although this is the default location, Aperture will allow you to store masters anywhere. And you don't have to keep all the images in the same place - some on external drives, some offline drives, some in the cloud. It's best to export files out of aperture or use the image browser to locate them. Use care not to move the files using Finder out from under Aperture or its database will break.